# How can I add a margin to the text editor in visual studio, with information related to the code and which scrolls with the code

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

The text editor in Visual Studio has several built in margins and it allows you to define your own custom margins.

I would like to implement a margin which shows information about the code lines in the editor, and which scrolls with the text.

There are two obvious examples:

- The glyph margin
- The line number margin

There are several samples from Microsoft:

[Creating a margin glyph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-margin-glyph?view=vs-2019) (also [here on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Todo_Classification)) shows how to render a symbol in the Glyph Margin, and how to use the tagging system.

There is also a template to create a simple margin in Visual Studio.

[image]

It is easy to modify this to create a margin on the left, but this is just a static canvas.

How can I make a custom margin which displays stuff related to the code, and which scrolls with the code like the glyph and the line number margins?

Is there a sample, from Microsoft or anybody else, which shows how to do something like this?

Comment: Please check if [this document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-margin-glyph.md) helps.

Comment: That is exactly the sample I was referring to above. It is a very good example using the glyph margin. I want to do something similar, using a custom margin. I want to show more than just a symbol.

Comment: The [GitDiffMargin project on GitHub](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin) might be a useful sample.

Comment: I have implemented the annotate function in [AnkhSVN2019](https://github.com/PhilJollans/AnkhSVN2019) using a technique like the GitDiffMargin project. The relevant code is mostly in the files AnnotationMarginFactory.cs, AnnotationMargin.cs, AnnotateMarginView.xaml and AnnotateMarginViewModel.cs, 
all of which are in the directory https://github.com/PhilJollans/AnkhSVN2019/tree/master/src/Ankh.UI/Annotate